# Model to create multiple varied instances of another model in Rails 4 without unnessary coupling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord

What is considered best practice for having one ActiveRecord model which, depending on the values it is assigned, generates instances of a separate model? I'm concerned that my models 'know' too much about each other and are becoming difficult to write tests for and am looking for the correct 'Rails way' of tackling this.

Essentially the first model is a specification that determines the number of instances and the attributes assigned to those instances of another model. I want to be able to change either that specification or the individual instances freely.

I am working on creating a budgeting app for my company. The idea is to track cash flows as a series of transactions represented by my `Transaction` model.

I don't want the user to have to manually enter each transaction (but I want them to be able to edit each one later if needed), so I've created `CashRevenue` and `CashExpense` models where the user can enter things like a start date, end date and growth rate which gets persisted to the database and then triggers a non-ActiveRecord model `TransactionBuilder` which processes the info and calls `Transaction.new()` the correct number of times and sets the attributes correctly.

To implement this, I have `CashRevenue` and `CashExpense`call `TransactionBuilder.build_transactions(self)` which assigns instance variables, calls a method to remove any existing transactions associated with the calling object (in case it's an update action).

Since revenue transactions are treated differently in the app than expenses, I'm checking the type by doing `@cashflow_type = cashflow_item.class.to_s` before the create.

It then creates the transactions as follows:

```
def self.add_transactions
  number_of_occurences.times do
    add_transaction
end

end

def self.add_transaction

  transaction = Transaction.new()

  if @cashflow_type == "CashExpense"
    transaction.cash_expense_id = @cashflow_item.id
  else
    transaction.revenue_id = @cashflow_item.id
    transaction.planned_number_of_customers = get_number_of_customers
    transaction.planned_arpu_amount = get_arpu_amount
  end

  transaction.planned_amount = get_transaction_amount 
  transaction.planned_date = get_transaction_date
  transaction.edit_method = "SYSTEM"
  transaction.user_id = @cashflow_item.user_id

  if transaction.save!
    @last_transaction = transaction
  end
```

Is there a better way to structure my app to achieve the same tasks while making my models less tightly coupled? I'm expecting this application to grow quickly in complexity so want to keep it as modular as possible.

Railroady diagram of my applications models: https://github.com/jamesconnolly93/investablemvp/blob/master/doc/models_brief.svg

Any help would be hugely appreciated!